# Is there a good .Net library out there for using custom Windows performance counters?

Tags: c#, amazon-simpledb, performancecounter

I would like to add instrumentation to an ASP.net MVC app I'm writing. Specifically, to keep track of cost associated with using Amazon's SimpleDB. I was surprised to find that my costs there were more than an order of magnitude greater than the rest of my Amazon usage fees combined!

I've read through [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx), and it's got some good tips, but I came away with as many questions as I arrived with. I'm not interested in learning a lot about performance counters, as this is a non-functional requirement. Is there a library (preferably open source) that makes it easier to add custom performance counters to a .Net app written in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://perfmoncounterhelper.codeplex.com/?

Comment: now I have :) Protip: ditch the installer binary and grab the source code to create your own installer.